# ORA-01403 when referencing page item in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am building an Oracle ApEx page to show charts of data. The data are entered on to a table as inputs, but the actual calculated metric can be different depending on what KPI is being viewed (AVG(VALUE_1); SUM(VALUE_1)/SUM(VALUE_2); etc.); these calculations are stored on a separate table. Since I want everything to be dynamic for use interactions, I am using a source of PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query. Here is a simplified version

```
DECLARE
    SQL_STMT      VARCHAR2 (32767);
    CALC_CLAUSE   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
    SELECT CALCULATION
      INTO CALC_CLAUSE
      FROM KPI_TYPES
     WHERE ID = 101;

    --when the value itself is entered, the results display as intended

    SQL_STMT := 'SELECT DATE, ' || CALC_CLAUSE || ' KPI_VALUE
    FROM DATA_VALUES
    WHERE TYPE_ID = :P_KPI
    GROUP BY DATE';

    RETURN SQL_STMT;
END;
```

As noted above, this functions as expected when the KPI's ID is manually entered, but I want this to be dynamic. I have a select list page item (P_KPI) for the user to choose the viewed KPI. Its value is actually set from a previous page with validation, so it should never be null.

When I update the CALC_CLAUSE condition:

```
WHERE ID = :P_KPI
```

I receive the following error:

```
ORA-01403: no data found
```

How can I reference this page item in the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with the stored function suggested by Littlefoot, I was able to use this solution:

http://vincentdeelen.blogspot.com/2014/02/interactive-report-based-on-dynamic-sql.html

I have a page process that creates a collection with the dynamic query string. The charts region SQL now queries from the collection, and I can use all of my page items to filter the data appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Code you posted is invalid (wouldn't compile) and explanation you gave is wrong. Although it is a *simplified version*, I'd prefer if you posted accurate information.

You said that SQL statement is

```
SELECT DATE, '||CALC_CLAUSE||' KPI_VALUE
FROM DATA_VALUES ...
```

while `CALC_CLAUSE` looks like

```
WHERE ID = :P_KPI
```

so the whole query looks like

```
SELECT DATE, WHERE ID = :P_KPI KPI_VALUE
FROM DATA_VALUES ...
```

which just doesn't make sense. What is that `CALC_CLAUSE`, after all? Shouldn't it be `AVG(VALUE_1)` or something like that?

---

As of `:P_KPI` item whose value seems to be `NULL`: it doesn't matter that you see it on the screen - it should be in the *session state*. The simplest way to do that is to submit the page, so - did you do it?

Try to create a stored function (in the database, not in Apex) and pass it P_KPI value as a parameter. Then test what you get, as well as the result. When working with dynamic SQL, it is a good idea to `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` the resulting statement (that would be `SQL_STMT` in your example), copy/paste it into SQL*Plus (or any other tool you use, such as SQL Developer) and see whether it works correctly.

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_stmt (par_kpi IN NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   sql_stmt      VARCHAR2 (32767);
   calc_clause   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
   SELECT calculation
     INTO calc_clause
     FROM kpi_types
    WHERE id = par_kpi;

   sql_stmt :=
         'SELECT DATE, '
      || calc_clause
      || ' KPI_VALUE '
      || ' FROM DATA_VALUES '
      || ' WHERE TYPE_ID = '
      || par_kpi
      || ' GROUP BY DATE';

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (sql_stmt);

   RETURN sql_stmt;
END;
```

Comment: I had neglected a single quote at the end of the SQL_STMT definition (now edited), which should help the code make more sense. The session state of the page item definitely has a value, but the error actually occurs on the development page, not the client page. It won't even let me save or run the page when I reference the page item at the top, but it works in the body of SQL_STMT. I'll try a stored function (that's certainly more scalable), but it should work on the page as well.

Comment: So I finally got a chance to test this solution, and unfortunately it won't work completely. When I test the stored function in SQL Developer, I receive a full query which I can copy and run, producing the correct results. However, when I use this function as the source for the ApEx chart, I get errors. If I reference page items as the inputs to the function, I get the ORA-1403 error; when I enter actual static values for the inputs, I get the error "No query has been returned by pl/sql block." (no Oracle error code). While this may be a good PL/SQL solution, it won't work in ApEx somehow.

Comment: ORA-01403 is *no data found*, which looks like you didn't pass :P_KPI item value to the function. Make sure it is in session state (which means that you don't just *see* it on the screen). The simplest option to do that is to submit a page, so - create a button, its action should be *submit*, and try again. As you've said, the function actually *works*.

Comment: That's a problem in all of this; I can't even save the changes to the chart source because it produces this error on the Page Designer. The page can't be saved while there are errors on the page. When I'm running the page (without the stored function), the page item most definitely has a value in the session state.

Comment: Huh, no idea ... it *should* work. If possible, create an example on apex.oracle.com and let us know credentials so that someone could have a look.